# Detect a fetch request in PHP

Tags: php, fetch-api

How can I detect requests from the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in PHP?
I am currently using the approach below to detect an AJAX request:

```
$context['isAJAX'] = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
```

Ideally I could detect Fetch requests in a similar manner. Does anyone have any techniques to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There’s no reliable way to distinguish a request made using the Fetch API from one made using XHR or from some AJAX library. The Fetch API doesn’t cause any unique headers to be sent.

If you just want to detect if a request probably came from frontend code running in a browser, you can by checking for the `Origin` header. Browsers add the `Origin` header to all cross-origin `GET`s. So if a `GET` request was made same-origin from a browser, it won’t have `Origin`.

And browsers send `Origin` for same-origin `POST`s, not just cross-origin `POST`s.

And browsers send `Origin` for XHR requests too, not just requests from the Fetch API.

So there’s no reliable way to detect on the server side if a request was made with the Fetch API.

Incidentally, if you’re checking for the `X-Requested-With` request header, all that’ll tell you is, the request was probably made with a common 3rd-party AJAX *library* instead of directly with XHR or the Fetch API. That’s because `X-Requested-With` isn’t a standard (that’s why its name starts with *`X-`*) and is never sent natively by browsers themselves but is by major libraries.

So I guess if you *don’t* see the `X-Requested-With` request header,  at least you know that the request probably wasn’t from code using any of the AJAX methods in any of the major libraries, though that just means it also could’ve been sent from `curl` or something instead of a browser.

And if you see the `Origin` request header but not the `X-Requested-With` request then at least you know the request was probably sent from a browser but not using a major library—though there’s some possibility it still could have been sent with `curl` or whatever, if somebody manually added an `Origin` header to the request.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. To clarify, I do not need to distinguish between requests made via XHR and Fetch - I need a general boolean value on any GET requests coming from the same-origin, whether they are XHR or Fetch. With this said, based on your answer, it seems that I could just check the `Origin` header. Would the absence of the `Origin` header confirm that it is indeed a GET request from the same-origin?

Comment: Yeah as far as `GET` requests initiated from JavaScript running in a browser, the absence of the `Origin` request header would indicate that the request was same-origin. (However, if someone explicitly set `mode: no-cors` in the request it would also lack `Origin`; but setting `mode: no-cors` is almost always a mistake, and requests that are created with that mode are almost never going to work the way the author intended, so I think that is an edge that can just be considered a programming mistake.)

Answer (score 10):

Add to fetch options
headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

Comment: This is a very sensible workaround/shim if you have control of the code where the fetch statement is.

Comment: Clever! Here's my implementation: `fetch(url, {method: 'get', credentials: 'same-origin', headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}})`

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
  fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'credentials': 'same-origin',
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       // or 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    method: 'POST'
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

I've started to use the `Sec-Fetch-Mode` header more recently. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Mode

If it's set to `navigate`, you can assume a user is requesting the page by opening it in their browser. Any other value in this header would indicate some form of async fetch call inside or outside the browser.

The only downside is that this may not be supported in some older browsers before this header was widely adopted. And of course the usual disclaimer— headers are easily spoofed, so use them as hints, not statements of fact.